# Cant understand the logic to nest multiple times the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my logic in the function.I'm trying to nest array X times so that it can look like a tree with children.I nested it with the first child but when i go deep i cant find solution to remove them from the Main array and add them deep.The "parent" key is the ID of the parent element that needs to have child.Any help appreciate.

```
function array_search_multidim($array, $column, $key){
    return (array_search($key, array_column($array, $column)));
}

public function get_all() {
    $full_menu = $this->Site_model->get_all_menu();
    usort($full_menu, function($a, $b){
        return strcmp($a->menu_order, $b->menu_order);
    });

    foreach($full_menu as $fm) {
        $mega_menu[] = array(
        'id'        => $fm->id,
        'text'      => $fm->title,
        'href'      => $fm->link,
        'icon'      => $fm->icon,
        'target'    => $fm->target,
        'title'     => $fm->name,
        'order'     => $fm->menu_order,
        'parent'    => $fm->parent
        );

        if($fm->parent != 0) {
            $child_menu[] = array(
            'id'        => $fm->id,
            'text'      => $fm->title,
            'href'      => $fm->link,
            'icon'      => $fm->icon,
            'target'    => $fm->target,
            'title'     => $fm->name,
            'order'     => $fm->menu_order,
            'parent'    => $fm->parent
            );
        }
    }

    foreach($child_menu as $cm) {
        $mega_menu[$this->array_search_multidim($mega_menu,'id',$cm['parent'])]['children'][] = array(
        'id'        => $cm['id'],
        'text'      => $cm['text'],
        'href'      => $cm['href'],
        'icon'      => $cm['icon'],
        'target'    => $cm['target'],
        'title'     => $cm['title'],
        'order'     => $cm['order'],
        'parent'    => $cm['parent']
        );
    }

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($mega_menu);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

For now i recieve array like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => Начало
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#top
            [icon] => fas fa-home
            [target] => _self
            [title] => Начало
            [order] => 1
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [text] => Споделен хостинг
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#shared
            [icon] => fas fa-home
            [target] => _blank
            [title] => shared
            [order] => 1
            [parent] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [text] => Софтуер
                            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#software
                            [icon] => fas fa-code
                            [target] => _self
                            [title] => software
                            [order] => 2
                            [parent] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => Интернет
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#internet2
            [icon] => fas fa-wifi
            [target] => _top
            [title] => Интернет
            [order] => 2
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [text] => Софтуер
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#software
            [icon] => fas fa-code
            [target] => _self
            [title] => software
            [order] => 2
            [parent] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [text] => Хостинг
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#hosting
            [icon] => fas fa-home
            [target] => _self
            [title] => hosting
            [order] => 3
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [text] => Споделен хостинг
                            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#shared
                            [icon] => fas fa-home
                            [target] => _blank
                            [title] => shared
                            [order] => 1
                            [parent] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [text] => Сервиз
            [href] => http://localhost/roni/#service
            [icon] => fas fa-wrench
            [target] => _self
            [title] => service
            [order] => 5
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [text] => Контакти
            [href] => http://localhost/#contacts
            [icon] => fas fa-address-book
            [target] => _self
            [title] => contacts
            [order] => 6
            [parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use arrays for that? It might be easier to use objects. Additionally, what is the exact problem with "removing from the Main array and add them deep"?

Comment: I cant find the logic to nest them 3 levels deep because in the example i got the array with ID: 3 - 1 level deep(ID: 4) and now the array with ID 4 must recieve deeper ID:5

Comment: Whatever that means: probably your algorithm should work recursive for such a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kept the initial data as objects because I wanted to use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to find the point in which I want to add the nodes.  But the basic logic is to look for any nodes that have a parent node, then search all of the leaf nodes to find if that is the node which is the parent.  If it is then just add the node...

```
usort($full_menu, function($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a->menu_order, $b->menu_order);
});

foreach ($full_menu as $key=>$menu )   {
    if ( $menu->parent != 0 ) {
        array_walk_recursive($full_menu, function (&$data) use ($menu)   {
            if ( $data->id == $menu->parent)    {
                $data->children[] = $menu;
            }
        });
    }
}

function translate ( &$menu )    {
    foreach ( $menu as &$menuItem )  {
        $out = array(
            'id' => $menuItem->id,
            'text' => $menuItem->title,
            'href' => $menuItem->link,
            'icon' => $menuItem->icon,
            'target' => $menuItem->target,
            'title' => $menuItem->name,
            'order' => $menuItem->menu_order,
            'parent' => $menuItem->parent
        );
        if ( isset($menuItem->children))    {
            $out['children'] = $menuItem->children;
            translate($out['children']);
        }
        $menuItem = $out;
    }
    unset ( $menuItem );
}
translate ($full_menu);
$full_menu = array_filter ( $full_menu, function ($data ) { return $data['parent'] == 0;});

print_r($full_menu);
```

The last parts I've added will reformat the elements to be the array format you wanted and then it filters out the root level menu to remove any items that have been moved.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you so much.Yes its way better to use objects

Comment: Actually i'm missing the text object of the children

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've updated the middle bit which translates the array contents.

Answer (score 1):

In the first foreach in get_all function you add element of $full_menu arrach to $mega_menu every time, event if $fm->parent != 0 (which means every child element is saved to the 1st level of array). Next you handle childs. You must save (at the 1st dimention on array) only those elements with $fm->parent == 0. You can do it by changing a condition in get_all.

```
function array_search_multidim($array, $column, $key){
    return (array_search($key, array_column($array, $column)));
}

public function get_all() {
    $full_menu = $this->Site_model->get_all_menu();
    usort($full_menu, function($a, $b){
        return strcmp($a->menu_order, $b->menu_order);
    });

    foreach($full_menu as $fm) {
        if($fm->parent == 0) {
            $mega_menu[] = array(
                'id' => $fm->id,
                'text' => $fm->title,
                'href' => $fm->link,
                'icon' => $fm->icon,
                'target' => $fm->target,
                'title' => $fm->name,
                'order' => $fm->menu_order,
                'parent' => $fm->parent
            );
        } else {
            $child_menu[] = array(
                'id'        => $fm->id,
                'text'      => $fm->title,
                'href'      => $fm->link,
                'icon'      => $fm->icon,
                'target'    => $fm->target,
                'title'     => $fm->name,
                'order'     => $fm->menu_order,
                'parent'    => $fm->parent
            );
        }
    }

    foreach($child_menu as $cm) {
        $mega_menu[$this->array_search_multidim($mega_menu,'id',$cm['parent'])]['children'][] = array(
            'id'        => $cm['id'],
            'text'      => $cm['text'],
            'href'      => $cm['href'],
            'icon'      => $cm['icon'],
            'target'    => $cm['target'],
            'title'     => $cm['title'],
            'order'     => $cm['order'],
            'parent'    => $cm['parent']
        );
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($mega_menu);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Yes,  but not i'm receiving the child in wrong parent if they are nested 3 levels down

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove an element from an array you can use unset.
For example

```
unset($mega_menu[4][0]);
```

Comment: i know but nesting it for example 3 levels down will cause me to not have a variable to get the data from

Comment: Can you explain further how that solves the problem? For a tree-like structure, you should also delete children of the deleted node